# Annoying Application on Mac Creating Unwanted File

Tags: macos, mac

Last year, I installed an application on my Mac called Pocketcam. A few days later, I have removed the app from my Mac by dragging and dropping it into the trash bin. Apparently by doing that, it didn't remove the application completely as there are still some files left on the computer that is creating a log file in my document folder. The file keeps coming back after deleting it numerous times.

So my question is, "how do I find the file that is creating that file and remove it completely from my Mac?"

Comment: I can't find Pocketcam for OS X to download – can you give us a link to the software you mean? Can you tell us how that log file is called?

Comment: It's this one. It's called PocketControl because it controls the pocketcam. http://www.senstic.com/android/pocketcam/pocketcam.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [Uninstaller](http://www.senstic.com/iPhone/PocketCam/UninstallMac.aspx) provided by the developer of PocketCam? I assume this is the program you refer to. According to the page:

> ```
> Download the Mac uninstall program. Double-click to run the "Uninstall Installer".  This will completely uninstall PocketControl from your Mac.  Please reboot your Mac after uninstall.
> ```

This should fix it!

Comment: The uninstaller is a .pkg so it's an installer. I just hate the idea of installing something to get something else uninstalled.

Comment: @superuser A .pkg file doesn't have to put a single file on your Mac, it can also remove files. Try to put the hate aside and just run it, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably some kind of automated process is running in the background.

- Check your *Accounts » Login Items* for remainders of the app. Delete them if necessary. For example, the "KiesViaWiFiAgent" starts up with my account in the following screenshot. Select it and disable it by pressing the <kbd>-</kbd> button below.

  [image]
- Check `/Library/LaunchAgents` or `/Library/LaunchDaemons` as well as the same folders in your `~/Library` folder for [daemons](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html). Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> from Finder to go there if the folders are hidden.

  These folders contain `.plist` files that may be started and run in background. Trash the files relating to the rogue software.

You can also use software intended to monitor applications for files created on your system that would in turn create the log file:

- Install [AppTrap](http://onnati.net/apptrap/) (or similar), then install your software again, trash its .app file, and let AppTrap remove everything related, not only the .app file.
- Install [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (or similar), install your software, drag its .app file to AppCleaner and let it examine all the files related, then delete those.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [uninstaller for pocketcam](http://www.senstic.com/iphone/pocketcam/UninstallMac.aspx).  They describe that you need to download and run it and after a reboot it will have removed all pocketcam parts from your system.

Comment: The uninstaller is a .pkg so it's an installer. I just hate the idea of installing something to get something else uninstalled.